# JQuery изнутри, поиск по DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

В JQuery для того что бы повесить обработчик на на все ссылки на странице достаточно вот такого кода

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

При этом если на страницу динамически добавить новый элемент `<a></a>` то событие сработает и на наём.

Я хочу понять как это сделано. На чистом JS получается вот так:

```
var a = d.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
    a[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
}
```

Но таким образом событие вешается только на элементы которые уже существуют и если добавить ещё один динамически, обработчика события на нём не будет.

Как это исправит ? И как этот момент реализован в jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример, описанный в вопросе

> ```
> $( "a" ).click(function() {
>      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
>   });
> ```

как раз не поддерживает обработку событий для динамически добавленных элементов.
Для обработки необходимо использовать функции:

```
  $('.container').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
     alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
```

или

```
  $('.container').on('click', 'a', function() {
     alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
```

В `Javascript`, честно говоря, не знаю существуют ли аналогичные методы. Как вариант, можно вешать события непосредственно при добавлении элемента.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется делегирование событий. Чтобы понять как это работает посмотрите эту статью: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Вкратце суть в том, в случае делегирования, обработчик события вешается на какой-то корневой элемент, например на document. Далее, по мере всплытия событий, внутри обработчика мы проверяем то, на каком узле DOM оно произошло, и если узел нам подходит, то выполняем нужное действие.

Пример кода из статьи:

```
table.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target; // где был клик?

  if (target.tagName != 'TD') return; // не на TD? тогда не интересует

  highlight(target); // подсветить TD
};
```

На jQuery конечно делать делегирование гораздо проще чем на чистом JS. Вся эта логика под капотом.

Comment: А можете добавить еще и пример кода, для наглядности =)

Comment: Да нет, я знаю как это работает, просто думал что они придумали что-то лучше. Дело в том что у меня сайт жрёт слишком много ресурсов и сначала я подумал что это из-за того, что все события у меня сразу присвоены в document. Если кто-то встречался с такой проблемой подскажите как справится.

Comment: @СтаниславДалинин слишком много обработчиков конечно могут привести к тормозам, но если уж привели, то приведут в любом случае, хоть на документе, хоть где. Скорее всего у вас вообще в другом проблема.